# How to handle lots of `mockImplentationOnce` calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs, tdd

I'm writing integration tests for a class that has a lot of requests. The requests are done through a `HttpClient` singleton.

So, to avoid making real requests, I mock all calls to `HttpClient`. The problem is, I have too many requests.

1. `HttpClient.get` is called to fetch a token.
2. `HttpClient.get` is called to fetch a resource.
3. `HttpClient.get` is called to fetch all customers from this resource.
4. `HttpClient.get` is called to verify if a single customer exists in another API.
5. Conditional: `HttpClient.post` is called to add this one customer to the API, if it does not exist.
6. `HttpClient.post` is called to add the resource to another API.

It's actually a little more complicated than that, because some of these calls are done multiple times (inside a loop), but you get the picture.

I wrote a test case for every scenario. One test case to simulate a failed request to fetch the token, another to simulate a failed request to fetch a resource and so on.

To do this, I wrote a "happy" scenario - where everything goes well -, using `mockImplementationOnce`. My `beforeEach` looks a little like this:

```
tokenResponse = { body: { token: 'some-token'}, status: 200 }
HttpClient.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => tokenResponse)
tokenResource = { body: <some-fixture-with-resources>, status: 200 }
HttpClient.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => tokenResource
(...)
```

To write the scenarios, I reassigned the returned variable

```
it('fails to fetch the token', () => {
  tokenResponse = { status: 500 }

  // code that calls my class
  // code that asserts that an error was thrown
}
```

Anyway, I managed to write simple test cases for all scenarios, but my `beforeEach` has a giant boilerplate. Besides that, now I want to write more advanced test cases where a request is done multiple times (n of customers > 1). It's getting quite complicated to handle all fixtures and keeping track of individual mocks.

Is this a common issue? Is there an easier way to handle mock implementations? I thought about something like `mockImplementationNth` but couldn't find anything.

Ps.: Changing the code itself is hard because it is legacy code and the APIs are a little clunky.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about isolating the scenarios into a `setupMocks` function with a default setting that could be overwritten in the test cases with another function. It would look something like this:

```
describe('Integration test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    setupMocks()
  })

  it('goes well', () => {
    expect(myClass.execute()).resolves.toBe(true)
  })

  it('fails to fetch the token', () => {
    overrideMocks('token-failed')
    expect(myClass.execute()).rejects.toEqual('some-error')
  })

  (...)
})
```

At least the test cases will look simpler.